# VSCode 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

As the title says, I get the following error when I try to run Java commands in the VSCode terminal:

'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

However, I am able to run these commands in my normal windows CMD, so I don't understand why it doesn't work in VSCode.

I have added the java bin path to the PATH environment variable.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Need to set your Java filepath in your vs code config.

Comment: Do you mean java.home? Because I have also done this. :(

Comment: Read the following page carefully, then check that you have configured your environment and/or VSCode settings appropriately: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements.  And if you set the environment variables after starting VSCode, exit it and restart it.  Environment variable settings are read when an application (e.g. VScode) starts up, and are typically not refreshed.

Comment: Whilst kind of annoying, reinstalling VSCode fixed my issues...no idea why. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I share my experience it may work for you.

1- Firstly, you can install java package extension for VS Code, you can search it easily, find it in the extension in VS Code, and choose one of them to install.

2- Another tricky thing happened for me is that, if you use terminals in VS Code, after changing environmental variables  or installing new extension, it's better to restart the computer, then open the VS Code, kill the current terminal tab and open a new one and try the `java -version` command again.

Regards

Comment: You can also open the command prompt (cmd) with admin privilege and execute the command. `set PATH = C`. After that, maybe restart the prompt and execute `echo %PATH` to see the value of **PATH**. Note that using PowerShell could not work the last command.