# "Java is not recognised as an internal or external command" in vs code even though I am trying to use kotlin. I properly set the path also

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code

I am downloading vs code for the first time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't use Kotlin nor VS, but maybe this will be helpful: [VSCode 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64445297)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors (whether correctly linked or not!) when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This error occurs because you have not installed the `Java JDK`.**

#### How to use Kotlin in VS code

First you need to install the following programs on your machine

- Install **Java JDK** on the computer system
- Install **Kotlin** on your computer system
- VS code install plugin **Kotlin Language**
- VS code install plugin **Code Runner**

**installation steps:**

1. Please install **Java JDK** according to [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial)

   [image]

   *After the installation is complete, you can run the `java -version` command in the **cmd** window to check whether the installation is successful*

   [image]
2. Download the **kotlin** compiler [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.31)

   [image]

   After unzipping, add the **bin** folder path to the system environment variables

   [image]

   *After the installation is complete, you can run the `kotlinc -version` command in the **cmd** window to check whether the installation is successful*

   [image]
3. Install plugins in VS code: **[Kotlin Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin)** and **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)**

**It is now possible to use Kotlin in VS code.**

*Use the play button in the upper right corner or right-click to select **Run Code** to run the code*

[image]

If you want the result to be output in the **TERMINAL** panel, please add the following configuration in **settings.json**

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

[image]